# how to insert the attributes of a postgres jsonb field into a key-value table?

Tags: postgresql, select, key-value, jsonb

I want to turn jsonb values into a key-value table within a single statement

My sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE public.searchdatacache
( querysig text, "values" jsonb );
INSERT INTO searchdatacache (querysig, values)
VALUES 
(
'ytApiSearch://Armageddon trailer',
'[
  {"VideoId"      : "xwseawq"},
  {"Title"        : "Armageddon"},
  {"PublishedAt"  : "2012/01/01"},
  {"Description"  : "Armageddon is a film"},
  {"ChannelTitle" : "Bruce Willis Movies"}
]'
)

SELECT jsonb_array_elements(values) from searchdatacache where querysig =    'ytApiSearch://Armageddon trailer'
```

returns:

```
"{"VideoId": "xwseawq"}"
"{"Title": "Armageddon"}"
"{"PublishedAt": "2012/01/01"}"
"{"Description": "Armageddon is a film"}"
"{"ChannelTitle": "Bruce Willis Movies"}"
```

the data returned by the select statement looks ok 
so far but now I want to use this select statement 
within an "INSERT INTO" statement 
to fill a key-value table.

these records should be filled into a new key-value table:

```
VideoId      | xwseawq
Title        | Armageddon
PublishedAt  | 2012/01/01
Description  | Armageddon is a film
ChannelTitle | Bruce Willis Movies
```

thanks in advance
Gerald

Answer (score 1):

Use `jsonb_array_elements` in the `from` clause along with `jsonb_each_text` to get the key value pairs ready to be inserted.

```
select s.key,s.value
       from searchdatacache cross join lateral
             jsonb_array_elements(values) as j(e)
    cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(j.e) as s(key,value);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1609e341d5c91109ce752bf6b0a891c0)